# BuildBot: execute build steps in parallel

Tags: buildbot

Is it possible to instruct BuildBot to execute build steps in parallel?

I've been looking through documentation and it only seems to be possible by actually generating multiple builds / build factories.

I'm not entirely sure about Builders and Workers: I have seen that adding workers will allow me to run multiple build requests simultaneously (multiple programmers submitting PRs), but using multiple builders doesn't seem to be intended for anything like this.

So, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple builders executing simultaneously, for example if they listen to incoming commits on the same repository; a single commit will start all listening builders. In this scenario you can control parallelism using `BuilderConfig`'s `canStartBuild` [argument](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/configuration/builders.html). And beware to have the builders work on separate resources!

Alternatively if you [trigger](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/configuration/schedulers.html#triggerable-scheduler) multiple builders from a single builder and 
specify `waitForFinish=False`, the triggered builders will run simultaneoulsy.

I believe you cannot execute build steps in parallel within a single builder. Regarding the workers, I can't tell you.